# Why Thread goed to sleep first and sets TextView later in Activity?

Tags: android, async-await

Here is the code e.g. of result set in android first activity with UI having 3 `EditText` and 3 `Button`s or `TextView`. I need to set values in 2nd `TextView` to display total marks which is calculated from first 3 `EditText` and sleep for 10sec in main method without using thread but I am getting op ie after going to sleep 10sec and immediately showing total `TextView` and navigated to next activity ie mentioned in code so how to wait for 10sec after setting total

```
  EditText etMarkOne,etMarkTwo,etMarkThree;
  TextView tvTMarks,tvTotal,tvGrade;
  int m1,m2,m3,Tmarks;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      inilizeViewControls();
      eventHandlingonViewControls(); 
   }

  private void eventHandlingonViewControls(){
      tvTotal.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  private void inilizeViewControls() {
     etMarkOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMarkOne);
     etMarkTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMarkTwo);
     etMarkThree = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMarkThree);
     tvGrade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGrade);
     tvTMarks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTMarks);
     tvTotal= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
  }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    m1 = Integer.parseInt(etMarkOne.getText().toString());
    m2 = Integer.parseInt(etMarkTwo.getText().toString());
    m3 = Integer.parseInt(etMarkThree.getText().toString());
    Tmarks = m1 + m2 + m3;
    tvTMarks.setText(""+Tmarks);

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Tmarks",Tmarks);
    i.putExtra(" m1", m1);
    i.putExtra(" m2", m2);
    i.putExtra(" m3",m3);
    startActivityForResult(i,1);
}
```

}

Comment: Please format the code. It's lazy to post code which is unreadable and sends a message that the question is not worth bothering with trying to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Handler` for your task (10000 in `postDelayed()` means 10sec = 10000ms):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

// do work before delay  here
...

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do work after delay here
        ...
       }
   }, 10000);
```

Comment: thanks need to delay by thread sleep() when clicked without use of thread